# Existence of general method for finding isolated singularities?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose I have some general complex function $f(z)$. Does there exist a general method for determining the set of *all* isolated singularities of $f$?

It seems to me that the closest thing to a *general* approach would be to expand $f$ in a Laurent series about every possible point and see if there are either an infinite number of (or finite number of) powers of $z^{-n}\ (n>0)$, but clearly this would be impossible to do for every $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The current most famous open problem is a particular case of that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "you *have* a function $f(z)$"?

Comment: You very likely don't have to expand as a Laurent series at *every* possible point.  If your expansion is a Taylor series with positive radius of convergence, you need not expand at any other point interior to its disk of convergence.  If you can find a reasonable set of such open disks that cover the plane except for isolated points, you're done...